# Does it break MVVM if I use PresentationFramework's enums in ViewModel?

Tags: .net, design-patterns, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Simple question (just tricky for me :D)

I need to pass a settings parameter from the ViewModel through the WindowManager of Caliburn.Micro to the Window.

I want to set some properties like WindowStyle, WindowStartupLocation, ResizeMode, etc, but I would need the enums contained in PresentationFramework.

Does it break the MVVM pattern to use em?

Thank you! :D

Comment: what enumerations are you talking about ? and on the other hand passing any enumerations via a method will probably never break MVVM.

Comment: @Nalesso, are you concerned about namespace pollution?

Comment: @GayotFow no, can you tell me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rigid specification for `MVVM` against which your question can be evaluated.  But one approach that has enjoyed some popularity with developers is to create an *interface* like this...

```
public interface IWindowStateBehaviour
{
    void Maximize();
    void Minimize();
    void Normal();
}
```

...that has the various functions you expect to use.  This one has three for setting the window state:  `Maximize`, `Minimize`, and `Normal` that essentially abstract and wrap an Enumeration.

An implementation of this interface looks like this...

```
public class WindowStateBehaviour : IWindowStateBehaviour
{
    public void Maximize()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
    }
    public void Minimize()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
    }
    public void Normal()
    {
        Application.Current.MainWindow.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
    }
}
```

...and this allows the VM to receive an instance of IWindowStateBehaviour via **dependency injection**.  It also is an abstraction that keeps the VM clean from any windows specific name spaces.

The big payback of this approach is that you can have a class like this for unit testing...

```
public class FakeWindowStateBehaviour : IWindowStateBehaviour
{
    public void Maximize(){}
    public void Minimize(){}
    public void Normal() { }
}
```

... which does nothing and does not obscure the testing process by requiring presentation assemblies.

You can use a similar technique for the start-up location, resize mode, and other parameters and inject them into your VM with `Unity` or whatever DI you are using.  So while the direct use of Presentation Framework's enumerations does not necessarily break `MVVM`, there are better techniques that promote abstraction and "separation of concerns".

Comment: Thank you for sharing man, that's a good solution, even though your example only covers MainWindow, but I think it's not that difficult to use an IWindowManager in it, maybe injecting the WM into the behavior, and adding a parameter for each method through which you can provide the calling ViewModel, so the WindowManager can retrive the associated view. Or even better to pass the View property of the Caliburn.Micro's IScreen interface, which usually vms inherit. Thank you for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

You could set these declaratively in the XAML of your view, by making your view a `Window` rather than a `UserControl`:

```
<Window ... 
  WindowStyle="None"
  ResizeMode="NoResize"
  ...>

</Window>
```

Comment: The WindowManager also accepts a collection a settings, for example in the ShowWindow method